# Erro Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo um banco de dados um tanto quanto simples para apresentação de um trabalho e estou encontrando o mesmo chato problema.

No caso temos duas tabelas, `funcionario[nome,cpf]` e `departamento[DNR,CPF do gerente]`. Aqui está o código:

```
CREATE SCHEMA empresa;
USE empresa;

CREATE TABLE funcionario (
   nome VARCHAR(30),
   CPF INT NOT NULL,
   DNR INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (CPF),
   FOREIGN KEY (DNR) REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTO(DNR)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTO
(
   CPF INT NOT NULL,
   DNR INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (DNR),
   FOREIGN KEY (CPF) REFERENCES funcionario(CPF)
);
```

Não entendi por que não posso fazer isso.
Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow Pedro. Fiz algumas alterações para melhorar a visualização, qualquer problema você pode reverter edições por meio [deste *link*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/62889/revisions).

Comment: Só não entendi o motivo de departamento ter uma chave em Funcionário. Isso cria uma relação 1-1, ou seja, um departamento só pode ter um funcionário. Talvez a chave precise estar somente em funcionário. Criando uma relação Funcionário pertence a um departamento e um departamento possui N funcionários.

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro acontece pois a tabela que será referenciada na *Foreign Key* precisa existir no momento de criação da chave.

Nesse caso você deve inserir as chaves em uma consulta separada:

```
CREATE TABLE funcionario (
   nome VARCHAR(30),
   CPF INT NOT NULL,
   DNR INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (CPF)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTO
(
   CPF INT NOT NULL,
   DNR INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (DNR)
);

ALTER TABLE funcionario
ADD FOREIGN KEY (DNR) REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTO(DNR);

ALTER TABLE DEPARTAMENTO
ADD FOREIGN KEY (CPF) REFERENCES funcionario(CPF);
```

Exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b9a06).

Answer (score -1):

Você não vai conseguir fazer isso, pois sua tabela `funcionario` aponta para a tabela `departamento` e vice-versa.

Você deve criar uma nova tabela para que sirva de ponte para as tabelas `funcionario` e `departamento`.

Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE funcionario (
   CPF INT PRIMARY KEY,
   NOME VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTO (
   DNR INT PRIMARY KEY,
   CPF INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE funcionario_departamento (
   CPF_FUNCIONARIO INT NOT NULL,
   DNR_DEPARTAMENTO INT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (CPF_FUNCIONARIO) REFERENCES funcionario(CPF),
   FOREIGN KEY (DNR_DEPARTAMENTO) REFERENCES departamento(DNR)
);
```

Abraço!

Comment: Se a relação não for n-n ele não precisa criar uma terceira tabela. Basta criar a FK depois que ambas estejam criadas.